# Multi-line ListView w/ ImageView on left side

Tags: java, android

I am required to create a project similar to that of the ff. pic. (My apologies for the use a siily pic, I have to make do with what is readily-available). 
[image]

I wouldn't say what I did was the best approach in making a 'dynamic' ListView but I'd be glad just to make what I currently have work. Anyway my implementation is as follows:

```
public class MultiLineListViewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = getSearchResults();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(this, searchResults));
}

private ArrayList<SearchResults> getSearchResults() {
    ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();

    SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
    sr1.setName("Name 1");
    sr1.setPhone("12345");
    SearchResults.setIcon(R.drawable.pic_one);
    results.add(sr1);

    sr1 = new SearchResults();
    sr1.setName("Name 2");
    sr1.setPhone("123456");
    SearchResults.setIcon(R.drawable.pic_two);
    results.add(sr1);

    ...

    return results;
}
}
```

public class SearchResults {

```
private String name;
private String phone;
public static ArrayList<Integer> iconsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public static void setIcon(int i) {
    iconsList.add(i);
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return this.phone;
}
}
```

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;

public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
    this.searchArrayList = results;
    //this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return searchArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return searchArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    ImageView imageView;

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

        imageView = new ImageView(context);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageResource(SearchResults.iconsList.get(position));

    holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txtPhone.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getPhone());

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtPhone;
}
```

The above code was successful in displaying the **Name** and **Phone** lines in the ListView, it's the addition of the image that's giving me the 'Force Close'.

Take note of the commented line **imageView = (ImageView) convertView;**
I have reduced it down to that particular line in that removing the comments causes the app to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: Whenever you get a force close that you're asking about in a StackOverflow question, please post the full stack trace.*

You're always creating a new `ImageView` when in fact you probably shouldn't need to create one at all. It should be defined in your custom item layout (which you should probably post as well in this case) just like the `TextView`s. You can use `findViewById` the same way and get it.

Comment: Your suggestion was on spot! Like you've said I've added an ImageView to layout.custom_row_view.xml, removed ALL declarations and instantiations of imageView inside getView(), did nested LinearLayouts (RelativeLayout works too) to arrange the views similar to the example.. and viola! It's working as intended now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

kabuko is right on both counts. (UPDATE: also his comment below should not be ignored.) I'm guessing that your `layout/custom_row_view` is a LinearLayout, which would mean that the commented line attempts to coerce a LinearLayout to an ImageView, which yes would raise an exception. Also, your `ViewHolder` class is superfluous, just define those TextViews as variables in your `getView()` like so...

```
// Assuming that layout/custom_row_view is a LinearLayout...
getView(yadda) {
   LinearLayout row;
   ImageView imageView;
   TextView txtName, txtPhone;

   if (convertView == null) {
      row = // inflate a new one
   } else {
      row = // get the old one
   }

   // fetch the views
   imageView = row.findViewById(...);
   txtName = row.findViewById(...);
   txtPhone = row.findViewById(...);

   // fill the views
   imageView.setImageResource(...);
   txtName.setContent(...);
   txtPhone.setContent(...);

   return row;
}
```

Ciao.

Comment: The `ViewHolder` class is actually a valid performance enhancement. `findViewById` isn't always cheap, and sometimes it's worth it to eat up a tiny bit more memory to save on that processing. See [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) for an example.